# Entity Framework Core returns null always except when using OrderBy?

Tags: c#, sql-server, graphql

I've been doing some testing with a graphql.net server, asp.net core, ef core and a northwind mssql database. Altho I ran into issues while doing getting the data from the database, what happens is that EF Core isn't returning the data that it should.

A Example of a model class:

```
public partial class Categories
{        
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Products> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Pretty straight forward, btw I've been using the db first approach, and this is actually generated with the scaffold tool from ef core.

What I want to do is that when I query a category without arguments in graphql that it returns me the first item in the table(if I want to query any other item I would do with a other method, and that is working).

In my graphql resolver when I query a field, in this case a `Category`(I don't want a list of categories at this point), I would usually do it really easy with the following code:

```
public async Task<Categories> GetOne(int CategoryID)
{
    Categories category =
    await _dbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefaultAsync(
    c => c.CategoryId.Equals(CategoryID));
    return category;
}
```

The upper code returns me a null, but what is really weird is that the following code also returns null:

```
Categories categories = await _dbContext.Categories
                                        .Where(c => c.CategoryId.Equals(CategoryID))
                                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

The only scenario where it works, but not as expected because it actually returns me the 2nd ID out of the table, and whatever I append on the end be that `FirstAsync`, `SingleAsync`, or even `LastOrDefaultAsync` the result is always the second row in the table, using code snippet:

```
Categories categories = await _dbContext.Categories
                                        .OrderBy(c => c.CategoryId.Equals(CategoryID))
                                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();`
```

I am fairly new to the Entity framework, so every help and suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Is there really a Category with the given ID?  With  OrderBy case you are are really ordering by a boolean and then getting the first, which naturally wouldn't return null if there is a row in Categories.

Comment: @CetinBasoz yes there is, in fact it's the smallest table with 8 rows.

Comment: does `Categories categories = await _dbContext.Categories.FindAsync(CategoryID);` also return null?

Answer (score 0):

So the behaviour of EF Core was ok, but the graphql resolver wasn't setup properly. After revisiting my graphql resolver, the actual methods did what they had to do.

I am very thankful for the input that all provided, and can mark this as resolved.